# GSL+OMP: Thread safe random number generators in C++

Tags: c++, random, thread-safety, openmp, gsl

I have a code in which I am trying to execute in parallel.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<omp.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iterator>
#include<string.h>
#include<vector>
#include<map>
#include<time.h>
#include<gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include<gsl/gsl_randist.h>

gsl_rng ** threadvec = new gsl_rng*[omp_get_num_threads()];
using namespace std;

int main(){
   clock_t begin = omp_get_wtime();
   vector<double> PopVals;
   map<int, vector<double> > BigMap;
   int Num1 = 100; 
   double randval;
   int Num2 = 10; 
   #pragma omp parallel
   {
       gsl_rng_env_setup();     
       for (int b = 0; b < omp_get_num_threads(); b++)
           threadvec[b] = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_taus);  
   }
   for( int i = 0; i < Num1; i++){
       PopVals.resize(Num2);
       #pragma omp parallel for
          for( int j = 0; j < Num2; j++){   
              randval = gsl_rng_uniform(threadvec[omp_get_thread_num()]);   
              PopVals[j] = randval; 
          }
       BigMap.insert(make_pair(i,PopVals));
       PopVals.clear();
   }

map<int,vector<double> >::iterator it = BigMap.find(Num1-1);
vector<double> OutVals = it->second; 

for (int i = 0; i < Num2; i++)
    cout << endl << OutVals[i] << endl; 

for (int b = 0; b < omp_get_num_threads(); b++)
        gsl_rng_free(threadvec[b]);

clock_t end = omp_get_wtime(); 
double elapsed_time = double(end - begin);
cout << endl << "Time taken to run: " << elapsed_time <<  " secs" << endl;
}
```

When I run this, there are 8 threads executing the nested loop in parallel, but I keep seeing the same random number for each thread. I attributed this behavior to lack of setting the seed, for each iteration. It would be great if somebody can point out, how can i generate unique random numbers in each iteration of the loop in a thread safe way.

The output of the above code is 0.793816, 10 times. Whereas, I want unique numbers for each of the values in the inner loop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues here.

## Using `omp_get_num_threads` out of parallel regions

Outside of a parallel region, `omp_get_num_threads()` always returns `1`. Use `omp_get_max_threads()` instead, it will return the number of threads for any upcoming `parallel` region unless manually overridden. Especially `threadvec` has only one entry.

## Don't initialize the environment in a parallel region

Calling `gsl_rng_env_setup` in a parallel region won't work properly. Also you are trying to allocate the whole vector of rngs by all threads... Simply remove the parallel region and use `omp_get_max_threads()` correctly. Or you could also do:

```
gsl_rng_env_setup(); // serial
#pragma omp parallel
threadvec[omp_get_thread_num()] = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_taus);
```

Allthough from the documentation it is not 100% clear if that is threadsafe, so just use the serial loop version.

## Properly seed your rngs differently

By default, all rngs are seeded with the same number, so obviously they will return the exact same sequence. Seed them properly with the thread number, e.g. `gsl_rng_set(threadvec[b], b * 101);`. Note that Tausworthe generators are weird. Those particular generate the same sequence of numbers when seeded with `0` or `1`.

## Implicitly shared variables

Your variable `randval` is defined outside of the parallel region, hence it is implicitly shared. You could force it to be private, but it is better to declare variables as locally as possible. That makes reasoning about OpenMP code much easier.

At the end, it looks something like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

// DO NOT using namespace std;

int main() {
  clock_t begin = omp_get_wtime();
  std::vector<double> PopVals;
  std::map<int, std::vector<double>> BigMap;
  constexpr int Num1 = 100;
  constexpr int Num2 = 10;
  gsl_rng_env_setup();
  gsl_rng **threadvec = new gsl_rng *[omp_get_max_threads()];
  for (int b = 0; b < omp_get_max_threads(); b++) {
    threadvec[b] = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_taus);
    gsl_rng_set(threadvec[b], b * 101);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < Num1; i++) {
    PopVals.resize(Num2);
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int j = 0; j < Num2; j++) {
      double randval = gsl_rng_uniform(threadvec[omp_get_thread_num()]);
      PopVals[j] = randval;
    }
    BigMap.insert(std::make_pair(i, PopVals));
    PopVals.clear();
  }

  std::map<int, std::vector<double>>::iterator it = BigMap.find(Num1 - 1);
  std::vector<double> OutVals = it->second;

  for (int i = 0; i < Num2; i++)
    std::cout << std::endl << OutVals[i] << std::endl;

  for (int b = 0; b < omp_get_max_threads(); b++)
    gsl_rng_free(threadvec[b]);

  clock_t end = omp_get_wtime();
  double elapsed_time = double(end - begin);
  std::cout << std::endl << "Time taken to run: " << elapsed_time << " secs" << std::endl;
  delete[] threadvec;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was right on point! Only one question: why can't we use "using namespace std"

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/620382) - Check out the top two answers.

Comment: If you are serious about using random numbers in parallel code you should read "Parallel Random Numbers: As Easy as 1, 2, 3" https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/38bc/7fc62136ec779d91b86b6e960a06d67b4a97.pdf

Comment: Thanks! Just came across that after I commented! *Will stick to good practices* :)

Comment: You said ``gsl_rng_taus`` is weird...The manual says *If different values of s ≥ 1 are supplied, then the generated streams of random numbers should be completely different. If the seed s is zero then the standard seed from the original implementation is used instead.* I guess the seed of the *original implementation* of ``gsl_rng_taus`` is 1, so you are actually using 1 as the seed when you set the seed as 0.